Identifying Necessary Microsoft Graph API Permissions for App Functionality
I'm developing a Microsoft 365 application using the Graph API to enhance email functionality. It involves reading, sending, and organizing emails through Graph API endpoints.
The app encounters issues with user-delegated permissions. It's configured to request User.Read, Mail.ReadBasic, and Mail.ReadWrite, but only works properly with full admin-level permissions.
After authorizing with a user from another external organization and granting all requested permissions, I checked the permissions granted to this external app in Microsoft Entra. Despite requesting permissions like User.Read, Mail.ReadBasic, and Mail.ReadWrite, the granted permissions shown in Microsoft Entra are only User.Read, openid, profile, and offline_access. This mismatch suggests a potential problem with how permissions are requested or granted.
The application works flawlessly with admin-level permissions, highlighting that the problem lies with delegated permissions, not the code or API interaction. I'm puzzled about the exact delegated permissions needed for mail operations and how to ensure they're correctly applied for universal functionality without admin rights.
Additional information about permissions set up in my project
Here is the scope of requested permissions which I have set up in the Azure applications:
Frontend:

Request for user information: /me

Permissions required: User.Read


Request for user's profile photo: /me/photo/$value

Permissions required: User.Read



Backend:

Request for user information: /me

Permissions required: User.Read


Request for user's messages: /me/messages

Permissions required: Mail.ReadBasic


Request for user's inbox and sent items folders, and list of mail folders:

/me/mailFolders/inbox
/me/mailFolders/sentitems
Permissions required: Mail.ReadBasic


Request to move a message to another folder: /me/messages/{message_id}/move

Permissions required: Mail.ReadWrite


Request for changes in a folder: /me/mailFolders/{folder_id}/messages/delta

Permissions required: Mail.ReadWrite



What I tried:
Configured the application in Microsoft Entra with delegated permissions: User.Read, Mail.ReadBasic, Mail.ReadWrite. Implemented API calls for reading user info and email operations.
What I expected:
The application performs all operations successfully for any user with delegated permissions, without needing admin rights.
What actually happened:
It works with admin-level permissions but encounters issues with restricted permissions. Specifically, it fails on write/modification operations on emails, indicating incorrect or insufficient delegated permissions. Upon review, the permissions were limited to User.Read, openid, profile, and offline_access, which is likely part of the problem.
Some additional information, which makes sense
Permissions request (authConfig/authConfig.ts)
import { type Configuration, type PopupRequest } from '@azure/msal-browser';

// Config object to be passed to Msal on creation
export const msalConfig: Configuration = {
  auth: {
    clientId: CLIENT_ID!,
    authority: AUTHORITY,
    redirectUri: '/',
    postLogoutRedirectUri: '/',
  },
  system: {
    allowNativeBroker: false, // Disables WAM Broker
  },
  cache: {
    cacheLocation: 'localStorage', // Cache location where tokens will be stored
    storeAuthStateInCookie: false, // Set to true to store the auth state in cookies
  },
};

// Add here scopes for id token to be used at MS Identity Platform endpoints.
export const loginRequest: PopupRequest = {
  scopes: ['User.Read'],
};

// Add here the endpoints for MS Graph API services you would like to use.
export const graphConfig = {
  graphMeEndpoint: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me',
};


The problem is solved.
The solution is to add additional rights to the scope in the authConfig.ts file: Mail.ReadBasic and Mail.ReadWrite.
UPDATE:
Everything is working, but to make your user sign in without administrator permission the organisation that develops the application has to be approved by the Microsoft team.
